# Prevent caching of data in browser

Tags: servlets

I am working on an assignment where I have to provide a link on an html page to another html page.

The link on Page 1 sends the user to a servlet. Inside of the get method in the Servlet, I get the referer, and if it is Page 1, I output the 2nd HTML page.

The goal is that if the user bypasses page 1, and goes straight to page 2 (the Servlet), they are sent back to page 1.

The 1st time I run the application, if I try to go directly to the Servlet, I get redirected to page 1, as expected. But, once I click on the link, it seems as though the servlet response is being cached, because I am sent to page 2, when I should get sent back to page 1.

I added the following line to my servlet code, but it still seems to be caching (my guess).

```
response.setHeader("Cache-Control", "private, no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate");
```

Answer (score 0):

Must be something with the browser inside of Eclipse ignoring the no-cache header. I tried it in Firefox, and it's behaving correctly.

Answer (score 0):

try to do the following :

```
  response.setHeader("Cache-Control", "no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate"); 
  response.setHeader("Pragma", "no-cache"); 
  response.setDateHeader("Expires", 0);
```

Hope that Helps